# Google Map resize and center, unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Depending on the state of my application, I want my google map canvas to be of different size, I change the size by using ng-class. When I call ToggleExploreMap(), the size of my google map changes, but the setCenter isn't applied properly. The position does change, but it doesn't change on my marker, but it is shifted to the top left of the marker position.

Is this a bug?

See this fiddle for an exemple of the seen behaviour. If you click the resize button, the map is resized, but you need to click a second time to actually have the map centered on the marker. http://jsfiddle.net/bkogdfva/1/

The Controller

```
    var exploreMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_explore_canvas"),myOptions);
    var $scope.ExploreMapStyle = "map_explore_canvas";       

      //Click Handlers
      $scope.ExploreDetails = function(marker){
        ToggleExploreMap();
        google.maps.event.trigger(exploreMap, 'resize');
        exploreMap.setCenter(marker.position);
      };

      function ToggleExploreMap(){
        if(exploreMode === "explore"){
          $scope.ExploreMapStyle = "map_explore_detail";
          exploreMode = "detail";
        }
        else{
          $scope.ExploreMapStyle = "map_explore_canvas";
          exploreMode = "explore";
        }
      };
```

The HTML

```
<div id="map_explore_canvas" ng-class="ExploreMapStyle"></div>
```

The CSS

```
.map_explore_canvas{
    width:1080px; 
    height:500px;
}

.map_explore_detail{
  width:400px; 
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: what problem your facing

Comment: @sanojlawrence the map isn't centered on the passed marker. The change of size does work, but the setCenter isn't applied properly.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is `<div`**`id`**`="map_explore_canvas" ng-class="ExploreMapStyle"></div>`

You refer div by **ID** so your css should be like bellow

```
#map_explore_canvas{
    width:1080px; 
    height:500px;
}
```

simple method to remember

`#` means id

`.` means class

and another problem

The HTML
Replace

```
 <div id="ExploreMapArea">
```

To

```
 <div id="map_explore_canvas">
```

and in css

Replace `.ExploreMapArea{....}`  to  `#map_explore_canvas{....}`

Comment: I assign my class with angularjs ng-class. The ExploreMapArea div is in my snippet, but it pretty much is useless.

Comment: @guiomie where is your snippet

Comment: i don't understand where is you snippet **(jsfiddle)**

Comment: My original post is all you need for code. I'll remove the ExploreMapArea because it seems to b confusing.

Comment: I added a fiddle, see initial post